# Remove rightView property from textfield swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm using rightview property to a textfield if it contains some text in it. I need to remove the property if the textfield doesn't contain any text. I have searched so many links but didn't find any answer for this. Please help me.

**To add rightView property**:

```
let cardImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: icon))
cardImage.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 70, height: self.cardTxtFld.frame.size.height-20);
cardImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
self.cardTxtFld.rightView = cardImage;
self.cardTxtFld.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
```

Comment: self.Cardnotxt.rightView = nil and self.Cardnotxt.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.never, Have you tried this ? . Can you elaborate the question ?

Comment: `Cardnotxt.rightView = Cardnotxt.hasText ? arrow : nil`

Comment: yes, I tried..it didn't work @indrajit

Comment: Not working @LeoDabus

Comment: You need to add a target and selector for Control event `.editingChanged` to your `UITextField` and add it to the selector method

Comment: I'm using this code in textfield shouldChangeCharactersIn method

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: Nothing happened..

Comment: edit your question and show your attempt

Comment: Btw not related to your question but you should take a look at Swift naming conventions https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/