# Swift: Is there a method for when someone taps a key on the keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

Is there a method I can use for when any button on the keyboard was tapped on the keyboard that puts input into a text field in Swift? How do I do something (For example display an image in the rightView of the UITextField) when any key that puts input in the UITextField (Excluding, for example, keys like caps lock and the emoji / switch language key) is tapped?

Comment: Have you checked `UITextFieldDelegate?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it very easily

Here is the code:

```
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let userImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "user"))
        userImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        self.txtField.rightViewMode = .always

        if let textFieldValue = textField.text,
            let textFieldRange = Range(range, in: textFieldValue) {
            let newText = textFieldValue.replacingCharacters(in: textFieldRange, with: string)
            if newText == "" {
                textField.rightView = nil
            } else {
                textField.rightView = userImageView
            }
        }
        return true

    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

If you face any difficulties in this so please let me know.

Comment: @JoeN same answer was given 30 minutes before this answer. I didn't get why you haven't accepted my answer???

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard will generally come in the case of UITextfield and UITextView try using the below-mentioned delegates.

So, In the case of UITextField

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
          shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
          replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Do something here...
}
```

When you use keyboard In Case of UITextView :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView
      shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
      replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    // Do something here...
}
```

Remember this, every time a user enters some character or pressed some key in keyboard this method will call and you will know the text he selected from the keyboard.

Comment: The question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: Is there a way you are someone else can put this in Swift?

Comment: @JoeN There is nothing here you can't see simply by looking at the reference documentation for `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UITextViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this delegate to control it:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   // String 键盘上新输入的字符，“”代表删除

    //返回true会添加进去，返回false会忽略掉
    return true
}
```

Comment: Also note that this can be called in cases where the user did not tap a key such as when the user performs a cut or paste.

Comment: Yes,It just response the code which will be insert to your control

Comment: As this condition,I think only make  a custom  inputView(a keyboard view) can  meet the requirements

Comment: This half works. The rightView will not go away now even after I backspace everything I type.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do by adding addTarget in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // do your works
    self.yourtextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)
}

@objc func textFieldChanged() {
     // do your work here 
}
```

What is addTarget?

> Associates a target object and action method with the control.

You write down addTarget with which action you want (i.e. editing change, textfield did begin editing, or end editing) and a selector method associates, when the control called (here editing change), this selector method will be called and you can handle your code what you want regarding the control

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways :

1. UITextFieldDelegate

   ```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      // Observer changes in text....
      return true
   }
   ```
2. Target-Action mechanism:

In your viewDidLoad add the following code:

```
self.textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTextChanged), for: .editingChanged)
```

And Implement method:

```
@objc func textFieldTextChanged() {
     print(self.textfield.text!)
}
```

Updated:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
     let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -10, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        rightView.backgroundColor = .red
        textField.rightView = rightView
        textField.rightViewMode = .always
    }


}

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if let text = textField.text, let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
            let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: string)

            if updatedText == "" {
                textField.rightView = nil
            } else {
                textField.rightView = rightView
            }

        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok. I used the first one. It almost works except when I hit backspace. The clear button is still there. How do I get it to disappear when I have backspaced everything out?

Comment: which clear button?? can you pls add it into your question??

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say, the image displayed in the rightView looks like a clear button.

Comment: Your 1. works but when I hit backspace and clear everything in the text field out, I want to also get rid of the rightView.

Comment: @JoeN then you just need to add check-in that method when your textfield text is empty. I think you just need to observe the sequence and I am sure you will get it.

Comment: @JoeN checkout this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894973/remove-rightview-property-from-textfield-swift-4

Comment: @JoeN if you are able to get the event of backspace it will be easy just to check when your textfield text is getting and accordingly just remove your right view.

Comment: there's no solution??

Comment: @JoeN checkout the solution

Answer (score 0):

My solution for a custom clear button:

Just add this outside of your class

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let clearButton = UIImageView(frame:
        CGRect(x: 7, y: 7, width: 16, height: 16))
    clearButton.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Clear")

    let iconContainerView: UIView = UIView(frame:
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 37, height: 30))
    iconContainerView.addSubview(clearButton)
    iconContainerView.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627451, green: 0.5568627451, blue: 0.5764705882, alpha: 1)

    textField.rightView = iconContainerView
    textField.rightViewMode = .whileEditing

    if let textFieldValue = textField.text, let textFieldRange = Range(range, in: textFieldValue) {
        let newText = textFieldValue.replacingCharacters(in: textFieldRange, with: string)
        if newText == "" {
            textField.rightView = nil
        } else {
            textField.rightView = iconContainerView
        }
    }

    return true

    }
}
```